# C - Concat Strings

Tags: c, string, char, concatenation

Trying to concat strings (*char) using C and having a lot of segmentation faults:

```
void printDateFormat( char *in ) { /* begin function printDateFormat */

   char *month;          // month by char
   int month_int;        // month by digit
   char *day;            // day by char
   char *year;           // year by char
   char *dateToken;      // date token in split
   char *formatted;      // formatted string

   dateToken = strtok (in, "/");
   month = &dateToken;

   formatted = formatted = getMonth(month);

   dateToken = strtok (NULL, "/");
   day = &dateToken;

   formatted = strcat (formatted, day);
   formatted = strcat (formatted, ", ");

   dateToken = strtok (NULL, "/");
   year = &dateToken;

   formatted = strcat (formatted, year);

   in = *formatted;

} /* End function printDateFormat */


char *getMonth( int d) { /* begin function *getMonth */

switch (d) {

  case 1:
     return "January";
 //    break;
  case 2:
     return "February";
 //    break;
  case 3:
     return "March";
 //    break;
  case 4:
     return "April";
//     break;
  case 5:
     return "May";
//     break;
  case 6:
     return "June";
//     break;
  case 7:
     return "July";
//     break;
  case 8:
     return "August";
//     break;
  case 9:
     return "September";
//     break;
  case 10:
     return "October";
 //    break;
  case 11:
     return "November";
//     break;
  case 12:
     return "December";
//     break;
   }

} /* End function *getMonth */
```

Input into printDateFormat() is expected as another string in the format: MM/dd/yyyy ... ie. 03/31/2013. Purpose is to turn that into: March 31, 2013.

EDIT:

Here's how I pass into `printDateFormat`

```
void option1( void ) { /* begin function option1 */

    char date[10]; /*user input date string */

    printf("\n\nEnter date [Format: MM/dd/yyyy]: ");
    fgets(date, 10, stdin);

    scanf("%s", &date);

    printDateFormat(date);

    printf("\n%s", date);

} /* End function option2 */
```

EDIT 2:

Ok, made a few changes but still no dice...

here's my compiler warning:

```
asgn9.c: In function `printDateFormat':
asgn9.c:224: warning: passing arg 1 of `getMonth' makes integer from pointer without a cast
asgn9.c:237: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

they refer to the use of `getMonth()` within my `printDateFormat()`

Here's my updated code, I still get a segmentation fault at the same spot...

```
void printDateFormat( char *in ) { /* begin function printDateFormat */

    char *month;          // month by char
    int month_int;        // month by digit
    char *day;            // day by char
    char *year;           // year by char
    char *dateTkn;      // date token in split
    char *formatted;      // formatted string

    dateTkn = strtok (in, "/");
    month = dateTkn;

    formatted = getMonth(month);

    dateTkn = strtok (NULL, "/");
    day = dateTkn;

    formatted = strcat (formatted, day);
    formatted = strcat (formatted, ", ");

    dateTkn = strtok (NULL, "/");
    year = dateTkn;

    formatted = strcat (formatted, year);

    in = *formatted;

} /* End function printDateFormat */

char *getMonth( int d) { /* begin function *getMonth */

    static char *months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
        "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    return strcpy(malloc(32), months[d]);

} /* End function *getMonth */
```

Comment: What do you pass to `printDateFormat`?

Comment: You don't need an ampersand in `scanf("%s", &/*<<== Here*/date);` this is just as good as `scanf("%s", date);`

Comment: For `getMonth()` how about `char *months[] = { "January", "February, ... }; char *getMonth(int d) { return strcpy(malloc(50), months[d]); }`

Comment: @DigitalRoss That's quite the way to violate encapsulation, abstraction, and every other principle of software design.

Comment: `char *in ... in = *formatted` -- this is only going to copy the first char of the string.

Comment: Oops, actually it's worse than that ... it will copy the first char of the string into a pointer; if you subsequently dereference the pointer, you'll have undefined behavior. You want `char** in ... *in = formatted` ... or better yet, just return `formatted` instead of storing it via a parameter. You should also compile with warning levels high ... the compiler should warn about `in = *formatted;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getMonth` returns a pointer to a string literal. Attempting to modify it(e.g., with `strcat`) isn't allowed -- it leads to undefined behavior.

I'd (strongly) suggest using `strftime` to handle formatting date and/or time strings for printing. This will not only reduce your formatting code to a one-liner, but also let you support localized results when/if you want as well.

Edit: if you can't use `strftime`, you'll want to build a formatted date in your own buffer, probably using `sprintf`:

```
char buffer[256];
static const char *months[] = {
    "January", 
    "February", 
    /* ... */ , 
    "November", 
    "December"
};

sprintf(buffer, "%s %d %d", months[monthnum], day, year);
```

Comment: its for a project and we're instructed to handle the conversion ourselves... so no use of `strftime`

Comment: @SnakeDoc But did you understand the essential point in Jerry's first paragraph? There's no magic in C like there is in other programming languages; if you're going to copy bytes with `strcat`, you need to have made room for them, and there's no room following a string constant.

Comment: @JimBalter I've posted an edit showing my now-modified code, however I'm still getting a segmentation fault. It appears I may have something wrong with my `formatted = getMonth(month);` line, since if I add a printf and display `month`, it shows correct, but if i add a printf to after the above line and display formatted, i get the segmentation fault.

Comment: bingo, thanks - I removed the `getMonth()` and used sprintf in `printDateFormat()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The value return by

```
getMonth(month);
```

is a point to a *constant* string. You cannot modify this string, including strcat(). You could change the function to meet your requirment as:

```
char formatted[MAXSIZE];      // formatted string
getMonth(month, formatted);

void getMonth( int d, char *cache) { /* begin function *getMonth */
    switch (d) {
        case 1:
            strcpy(cache, "January");
            return;
        ......
}
```

After that, you could continue to modify the content in the char array "formatted".

Comment: Yes, this piece of code just demo the idea. It did not take any error check or security check.

Comment: Right, but rookies take these answers, develop bad habits, become professional programmers, write tons of exploitable code, and we've seen the results.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am a newbie here. I will consider the security issues in my following answers. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: No need to apologize. Many other answers do the same, including on this page. Thanks for paying attention to me and caring about the point. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated any memory for formatted.  Change the declaration of formatted to

`char formatted[80];`

and change the first assignment into formatted to

`strcpy ( formatted, getMonth ( month ), sizeof ( getMonth ( month ) ) );`

and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your post is correct, then the problems are

```
month = &dateToken;
....
day = &dateToken;
....
year = &dateToken;
```

strtok return char *, so just remove & from each 'dateToken'.
And your prototype of 'getMonth' input is 'int' type, but you give function is 'char *' type,
'switch' table will not recognize non-digit table case.

Answer (score 1):

C is not a language for string processing.  If you possibly can, use C++ and std::string.

One way to do this in C is to define a large `char buffer[BUFFERSIZE]` buffer to copy the two string into in order to concatinate them.  Be careful that you don't overrun the buffer!

You can also malloc/free the buffer, but that's another set of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve some of your problems and simplify the code with:

```
char *getMonth(int d) {
  static char *months[] = { "January", "February", "March",
    . . .
  };

  return strcpy(malloc(60), months[d]);
}
```

This way,

- the return value is writable
- it has additional space for your strcat() ops

---

<sup>For industrial-strength, you may want to check the return value of `malloc()`, see if `n` is in range, and things like that.</sup>